# Solve parametric equation with summation

Tags: equation-solving

I want solve this equation and find k.

```
 Sum[Exp[-k^2*A (HarmonicNumber[n + d] - HarmonicNumber[d]) + 
  B*k*HarmonicNumber[n]], {n, 1, 100}] == -1 + Exp[k^2]*(1 - r)/r
```

A, B and d are constants and I need to find k over these constants.
I try to use FindRoot and Solve but don't give me the answer.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = 1; B = 2; d = 10; r = 1/10; (*Assumed parameters *)

EQ = Sum[Exp[-k^2*A (HarmonicNumber[n + d] - HarmonicNumber[d]) + 
  B*k*HarmonicNumber[n]], {n, 1, 100}] == -1 + Exp[k^2]*(1 - r)/r;

FindRoot[EQ, {k, -1}]

(*{k -> -0.294614}*)

FindRoot[EQ, {k, 4}]

(*{k -> 3.65005}*)

NSolve[EQ && -10 < k < 10, k]

(*{{k -> -0.294614}, {k -> 3.65005}}*)
```

Comment: yes  I know.  But I need find K over A and B . I don't want to use assumed values for A and B

Comment: @caren Please clarify your question, because you didn't mention for A and B?

Comment: A and B are parameters in this equation. I need find 'k' over this parameters, not for assumed values for A and B. Just For example " k = 2 A + 4 B /A".

Comment: @caren. For general a mathematically is impossible to obtain a symbolic(analytic) solution, because there is a lack of tools in mathematics to solve this equation.

Comment: So you say I can't solve it in Mathematica?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I don't find my question answer but learn a new things from your answer. thanks.